# Can setrlimit be used to force mmap to return VA within 64GB range?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mmap, luajit, setrlimit

I am working on a ARM64 server and trying to make an old program work.
I don't have to source code, just a binary.

The binary uses a LuaJit which does not support 48bit Virtual Address(VA). However, my kernel uses 48bit VA.

LuaJit uses mmap to allocate memory.

I want to make mmap always return a 47bit or lower VA.
I noticed setrlimit can limit a processes virtual address range. Is it just about quota or does it enforce a VA space limitation?

If it limits VA range, I think I can preload a dynamic library and call setrlimit be mmap is called.

Comment: "Is it just about quota or does it enforce a VA space limitation?" - [setrlimit](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) is all about **quota**, it has nothing common with bitness of the virtual address. Not sure how to limit bitness to 47 (or lower)...

Comment: According to [the relevant LuaJIT issue](https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/issues/49), the issue should be resolved in version 2.1, if you can swap it out. If that doesn't help you could probably wrap `mmap` with a preload library and implement something like their solution (linear/random probing until you get a usable address)

Comment: @Hasturkun Yes, I am trying to wrap mmap, thank you.